# How can I assign an event to a newly created movie clip in flash using action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a flash movie that pulls in xml and spits out banners in a loop.  However I need to provide carousel style functionality by having a list of buttons on the banner which provide a 'go to' banner link i.e 1 2 3 4 5 etc.

I can get it to create a movie clip as it loops through the xml to create the goto link, but it’s the Click functionality I am having an issue with.  Essentially targeting the newly created movie clip buttons.

The function creaBottone successfully creates a movie clip that sits on the banner which gets a number passed from an array, the onMouseDown function should pass the desired banner number in to hopefully go to the correct banner.  I hope that makes sense.

Here is the code:

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

stop();

// Load data
var Articles:Array;
var Data:XML = new XML();

Data.ignoreWhite = true;
Data.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void
{

    if (success)
    {

      var ArticleCount:Number = Data.firstChild.childNodes.length;
      _global.maxDepth = ArticleCount * 2; //max depth that an Mc can be...

      //         homepage  .article      .image        .value 
      //trace(Data.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.toString());

      //create Array
      Articles = new Array();

      //loop through the articles
      for (i:Number = 0; i < ArticleCount; i++)
      { 

        var Node:XMLNode = Data.firstChild.childNodes[i];

        var Article:Object =
        {  

          Duration : Node.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
          BannerImage : Node.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue,
          Blurb : Node.childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue,
          Link : Node.childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue

        };

        Articles.push(Article);

        creaBottone(i);

      }//end of 'for'

      playAnimation(Articles);
    }//end of 'if'

};
//Data.load(xmlpath);
Data.load("Homepage.xml");


function playAnimation(articlesArr:Array) 
{

  _global.mcArray = new Array();
  _global.totalArticles = articlesArr.length;
  _global.durationArray = new Array();
  _global.linkArray = new Array();

  var tweenTime:Number = 2; //time in seconds for an article to fade in/out 
  var globeDuration:Number = 3000; //milliseconds
  var currDepth:Number = _global.maxDepth;

  for(var i:Number = 0; i < articlesArr.length; i++)
  {

    var mc = bannerCont.attachMovie("article_mc", "article"+i, currDepth);
    mc.gotoAndStop(1);

    linkArray[i] = articlesArr[i].Link;


    mc.imgCont._alpha = 100;
    var imgRef = mc.imgCont.createEmptyMovieClip("img", 100);

    var myListener = new Object();
    var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();

    myListener.mc = mc;
    myListener.onLoadInit = function () {

      var aScale:Tween = new Tween(this.mc.imgCont, "_alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 100, .5, true);

    };

    loader.addListener(myListener);
    loader.loadClip(articlesArr[i].BannerImage, imgRef);

    mc.blurbField.text = articlesArr[i].Blurb;

    mcArray[i] = mc;
    durationArray[i] = articlesArr[i].Duration;
    currDepth -= 2;

  }

  var globe_mc = bannerCont.attachMovie("globeMc", "globe", _global.maxDepth + 1);
  globe_mc._x = Stage.width/2;
  globe_mc._y = Stage.height/2;
  playGlobe(globe_mc);

  _global.currArticleIndex = 0;
  var curr:Number = _global.currArticleIndex;
  setTimeout(showArticle, globeDuration, mcArray[0], tweenTime, (durationArray[0] * 1000), curr);

}


function showArticle(article:MovieClip, tweenTime, duration, currArticleIndex)
{

  //trace("global:"+_global.linkArray[currArticleIndex]);
  _root["urlText"] = _global.linkArray[currArticleIndex];

  if(_global.linkArray[currArticleIndex] != null)
    _root.btn.enabled = true;

  article.gotoAndPlay(1);
  article.linkBtn.enabled = true;
  var globeDuration:Number = 3000;
  var totalDuration:Number = duration;// + globeDuration;
  trace(totalDuration);
  setTimeout(fadeArticle, totalDuration, article, tweenTime, currArticleIndex);  

}

function fadeArticle(article:MovieClip, tweenTime, currArticleIndex)
{

  _root.btn.enabled = false;

  var aScale:Tween = new Tween(article , "_alpha", Strong.easeIn, 100, 0, tweenTime, true);
  var depth:Number = article.getDepth();
  var globeMc = loadGlobe(depth);

  aScale.onMotionFinished = function() 
  { 
    playGlobe(globeMc);

    currArticleIndex += 1;

    //if the currArticleIndex falls outside the article array boundaries
    if(currArticleIndex >= _global.totalArticles)
    {

      currArticleIndex = 0;
      var thisMc = bannerCont["article"+0];
      var aScale:Tween = new Tween(thisMc , "_alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 100, tweenTime, true);  

      aScale.onMotionFinished = function(){ 

        resetAlphas(_global.mcArray); //bring all the mc's alpha levels back to 100

      }


    }

    var mc = _global.mcArray[currArticleIndex];
    var duration:Number = parseInt(_global.durationArray[currArticleIndex]) * 1000;

    setTimeout(showArticle, 3000, mc, tweenTime, duration, currArticleIndex);  
  }

}

function loadGlobe(depth:Number):MovieClip
{

  var globe_mc = bannerCont.attachMovie("globeMc", "globe", depth-1);
  globe_mc._x = Stage.width/2;
  globe_mc._y = Stage.height/2;
  globe_mc.gotoAndStop(1);

  return globe_mc;

}

function playGlobe(globe_mc:MovieClip)
{

  globe_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);

}

function resetAlphas(array:Array)
{

  for(var i:Number = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {

    var mc = bannerCont["article"+i];
    mc._alpha = 100;

  }

}

function getNextArticle(mcArray:Array, currIndex:Number)
{ 

  var depth:Number = _global.maxDepth - ((currIndex+1)*2);
  var mc = bannerCont.attachMovie("article_mc", "article"+(currIndex+1), depth);
  mc.blurbField.text = mcArray[currIndex+1].blurbField.text;
  //trace("here:"+mc.blurbField.text);

}

function creaBottone(currIndex:Number):Void
{
    mymcn = eval("container"+currIndex);
    var mymc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip(mymcn, this.getNextHighestDepth()+currIndex);
    var positionx = 30 + (currIndex * 30);                      
    var positiony = (Stage.height - 35);    
    mymln = eval("label"+currIndex);
    var myml:TextField = mymc.createTextField(mymln, 1, positionx, positiony, 20, 20);
    myml.background = true;
    myml.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    myml.text = String(currIndex+1);
    myml.border = true;
    f_myTxt = new TextFormat();
    f_myTxt.align = 'center';
    //f_myTxt.color = 0xDDDDDD;
    myml.setTextFormat(f_myTxt);
    mymc.onMouseDown = function() {
    getNextArticle(_global.mcArray, currIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you strip useless code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
mymc.currIndex = currIndex;
mymc.onMouseDown = function()
{
    getNextArticle(_global.mcArray, this.currIndex);
}
```